# How to add Android Studio plugin as dependency in Gradle?

Tags: android-studio, gradle, testng, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I installed the TestNG plugin through Android Studio. On my filesystem the following files were installed:

```
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\testng\lib\testng.jar
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\testng\lib\testng-plugin.jar
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\plugins\testng\lib\resources_en.jar
C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\gradle\gradle-2.2.1\lib\plugins\testng-6.3.1.jar
```

I added the the TestNG dependency to the `build.gradle` of my **Module**--not "Project":

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.2.0'
    testCompile 'testng:testng:6.3.1' // Added this line
}
```

But Gradle couldn't find the library:

```
Error:Gradle: A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugUnitTestCompile'.
   > Could not find testng:testng:6.3.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/testng/testng/6.3.1/testng-6.3.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/testng/testng/6.3.1/testng-6.3.1.jar
         file:/C:/Users/UserFoo/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/testng/testng/6.3.1/testng-6.3.1.pom
         file:/C:/Users/UserFoo/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/android/m2repository/testng/testng/6.3.1/testng-6.3.1.jar
         file:/C:/Users/UserFoo/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/testng/testng/6.3.1/testng-6.3.1.pom
         file:/C:/Users/UserFoo/AppData/Local/Android/sdk/extras/google/m2repository/testng/testng/6.3.1/testng-6.3.1.jar
     Required by:
         MyBlackjack2:app:unspecified
```

How do I add TestNG to the search path? On the other hand, Android Studio installed the plugin in that location for a reason, but what's the best way to include it in my project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use TestNG 6.9.4, which is distributed on both JCenter and Maven (6.3.1 is on Maven Central only, which you don't seem to have in your repositories list).

Comment: That does indeed fix it; the build succeeds now, thank you. But I'm confused why the "Plugins" dialog in the IDE searches, as you say, Maven Central yet new projects in AS--by default--only enable the JCenter repo. I don't understand why it needs to fetch from the repo anyway, the "Plugins" dialog in AS already fetched and installed the plugin.

Comment: In fact Maven Central already has [v6.9.4](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Ctestng) so I have no idea where the "Plugins" dialog in AS fetches plugins from.

Comment: No explanations there, probably a glitch in your Android Studio configuration? Can you accept the answer if it solved your problem? Thanks!